# Small_image not showing up

Tags: magento-1.7, image

My media directory permissions is 755, all images are showing up on the frontend except those defined as small_image with the following code:

```
 <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_prod, 'small_image')->resize(47,47); ?>" width="47" height="47" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_prod->getName()); ?>" />
```

I don't know how to check the ownership of the folder (I read about it somewhere but I have no access to ssh on the server I'm working on).

The small image is not on the ftp, so it's not been created at all and the url simply returns a 404.

What else do I look at? I tried deleting htaccess on media folder but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh boy I think I missed the simplest way to approach this. I had already cleared the cache from the admin panel but now I renamed `media/catalog/product/cache` to `_cache` and everything was fine and dandy. I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Using the 'clear images cache' button from Admin > Cache Management is functionally similar to what you've done without actually requiring ssh access.

Comment: I did do that but didn't work, I don't know why?

Comment: Sounds like your FTP/SSH user isn't the same as the PHP user. So your permissions of 755 won't allow the server to actually read/write as group.